# Laravel 9 Validation: array is optional but its keys are required: required_array_keys and nullable don't work together

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-8

## Summary

1. Context
2. Sources

   2.1. Unit test

   2.2. FormRequest's rules method
3. Behaviors

   3.1. Actual behavior

   3.2. Expected behavior
4. Question

---

## Context

In a Unit test, I want to send data to a `FormRequest` in a REST call. I am testing the behavior of the validation rules I've written in the `rules` method of the `FormRequest`.

## Sources

### Unit test

```php
    public function test_detach_user_job_status()
    {
        $response = $this->put(route('users.update', ['user' => $this->applier['id']], [
            'job' => [
            ]
        ]));
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

### FormRequest's rules method

```php
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'nullable|string',

            'job' => 'nullable|array:id,attach_or_detach,message|required_array_keys:id,attach_or_detach',
            'job.id' => 'integer|gt:0',
            'job.attach_or_detach' => 'boolean',
            'job.message' => 'required_if:job.attach_or_detach,true|string',
        ];
    }
```

## Behaviors

### Actual behavior

The test succeeds.

### Expected behavior

The test fails. Indeed, the array `job` is provided but no keys `id` or `attach_or_detach` or (eventually) `message` are provided, whereas the validation rules do specify: `required_array_keys:id,attach_or_detach`.

Also, if no `job` array is specified at all, then the validator must not reject the request because this array is not provided, nor its keys: it's perfectly normal since the array must be optional (it is `nullable` to provide this feature).

## Question

Why doesn't Laravel make my test fail since my nullable (= optional) array is provided, and that its keys are required?

Comment: I've never actually used `required_array_keys` rule; not sure why it's not behaving as you'd expect. Curious, does this pass if you do `'job.id' => 'required|integer|gt:0'` (and similar with `'job.attach_or_detach' => 'required|boolean'`)?

Comment: Doubt anything with required works with nullable, maybe add everything in array except "job" and if(isset($this->request->job)) {$arr["job" => "array:id,attach_or_detach,message|required_array_keys:id,attach_or_detach];} then return $arr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't put the correct input. you should put the post body to `put()` method instead of `route()` method

change this:

```
    $response = $this->put(route('users.update', ['user' => $this->applier['id']], [
        'job' => [
        ]
    ]));
```

to:

```
    $response = $this->put(route('users.update', ['user' => $this->applier['id']]),
        [
            'job' => []
        ]);
```